# Define specific dates in a script - unix date

Tags: c, unix, date, ocaml

I searched for a way to define specific weekday of the month to operate a switch function in a audio broadcasting language script called "Liquidsoap". that language is built using C and oCaml and eventually outputs to IceCast.

I just need someone to simplify this code for me..i have no idead how to translate this into what i need..

```
use the date
function from unix to build a function which will choose the good day (and
do almost whatever you want in this way). For instance,

# Function returning true if this is a good day and false otherwise
def good_day() =
  # Name of the current day
  day_name = get_process_output("date +%A")
  # Remove trailing \n
  day_name = string.replace(pattern="\n",fun (_) -> "", day_name)
  # Number of current week
  week = int_of_string(get_process_output("date +%U"))
  # Return true on tuesday every four week
  (day_name == "Tuesday") and (week mod 1 == 0)
end

out = switch([(good_day, good_day_playlist), ...])
```

I need basically to define a weekday of the month in there...lets say, second tuesday of the month...

Comment: What is the question? What do you expect it to do? In what sense doesn't it do that? What have you tried? This "question" makes no sense at all...

Comment: sorry if i didn't explain my self better..i didn't try this script because i dont know how to utilize it to my need. and what i need is basically to define a weekday of the month in there...lets say, second tuesday of the month...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `time` and `mktime` in C standard library `<time.h>` to get a struct that includes a member corresponding to the current weekday (0-based): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/